# What is this weird stone chest?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I found this chest which looks like it's made of stone. I can't open it, even with a key. How do I get in there?

[image: Image of stone chest]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to blow it open with a bomb. The loot they contain is similar to Golden Chests.